# How do i add new records in array and update records from an array in the data base Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is the data i am receiving and would want to add new records if the id is not present in the array and also update the records if there is no id in the array

my Models:
class Course < ApplicationRecord
has_many: topics
belongs_to :user
end

class Topic < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :course
belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
has_many :courses
has_many :Topics
end

This is the array am receiving from Rails API via PostMan
[
{
"title" : "Topic Name",
"path_url" : "https://resource-asws-path-url"
},
{
"id" : 2311,
"title" : "Topic Name",
"path_url" : "https://resource-asws-path-url"
}
]

this is how am doing it:

```
 if params[:topics].present?
                    attributes_list = [params[:topics]].to_s
                    attributes_list.each do |attributes|
                      if attributes.key?('id')
                        Topic.find(attributes['id']).update!(attributes)
                      else
                        Topic.create!(attributes)
                      end
                    end
I need to get attributes dynamically from the request from post under params[topics]
```

Comment: Please share how exactly you use Postman to send that data to your application and how exactly the log file entry for that request looks like.

Comment: Guys have been able to solve the issue:    if params[:topics].present?
                        @param=[params[:topics]]
                        @json=JSON.parse("#{@param[0]}")
                        p @json[0]
                       @p= @json.each do |topic|
                        if topic.key?('id').present?
                         @w= Topic.find(topic['id']).update(topic)
                            else
                           @regex= @course.topics.create!(topic) 
                        end
                      end
                  end 
                    end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do that with a condition:

```
if params[:topics].present?
  JSON.parse(params[:topics]).each do |topic|
    if topis.key?('id')
      Topic.find(topic['id']).update!(topic)
    else
      Topic.create!(topic)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks the array is generated from the api, can you please post an image

Comment: how do i get the  attributes from the API request? Dynamically and pick them from attributes_list

Comment: Hey @spickermann, thanks for answering my question, However i have edited the question, i want to add these records from Rails API to the database, How do i get those attributes sent in the request from the API via Postman?

Comment: I am running into this error each time i try to run the above code: NoMethodError (undefined method `key?' for "[{\"name\"":String):

Comment: NoMethodError (undefined method `key?' for "[\"330087\"]":String):

Comment: Yes, how do i get that?

Comment: Hey Spickermann, this is what am getting NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for #<String:0x00007ff2231f7c60>): after your latest update. the request should ruby JSON string

Comment: Thanks @Spickermann. It worked like charm thanks very much. Indeed found this and i added other validations and it worked LIke Charm. Keep the Spirit of assisting.

Comment: Thanks Spickermann, let me upvote, then i wanted to know what if i want to check an empty array  and then delete all records from the DB i would assume the user has deleted all topics if it returns an empty array in the topics parameter.

Comment: Perhaps just `Topic.destroy_all if params[:topics].blank?`?

Comment: I want where the array is empty for example its sent like this [{}] without anything in it,  i can destroy all  records from the DB and if its not blank then i create or update what has been sent. Can you update the above solution for me?

Comment: The example in the above will delete all topics when you pass in an empty array (`[]`) or no topics params at all.

Comment: Can you add the line in the above code you provided. Thanks